# Taking medications while fasting

Tags: women, sawm, menses

I missed some days of fasting during Ramadan because of irregular menstruation/istihadah. I’m planning on making those up but I’m on birth control now to help regulate my periods and I have to take it at the same time everyday. Is it okay for me to fast and take my medication as usual? If not, how can I make those fasts up?

edit: I missed 14 days because I didn’t know the rulings on irregular bleeding/istihadah and I wasn’t sure if I could fast or not since it was my first time fasting during Ramadan. I have to take my medicine at the same time everyday so how can I make up those fasts

Comment: Please be specific. How many days that you missed the Ramadhan before? As far as I know, once you take medicine, your "fasting" is not valid and not counted as fasting. Maybe this will answer your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/9283/45948

Comment: You have to take a medication the same time everyday, why can't you set this time to fall within the night period when you are permitted to eat and drink?